# How to communicate with plymouth (splash screen software) programmatically?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, plymouth

I'm not running X server or Wayland, I'm writing an OpenGL application and I want it to stop right after plymouth starts displaying shutdown splash screen...

I tried simply stopping it on shutdown, but there is some time between my app and splash where you can see linux console and I would prefer to avoid that.
Sadly I can't just put a delay before stopping my process since this time varies between boots...

How can I communicate with plymouth and know what it is currently doing?

Does it create some files on file system I could put a watcher on?

I should also mention that I'm using systemd - maybe it can be utilized to synchronize my process with plymouth?